# C# - How to get the value instead of id's in a List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops

I have a List containing objects. Each object holds an 'mta' Id

```
List<Elements.ReservationElement> reservationList = new List<Elements.ReservationElement>();
```

How can I get the corresponding value (instead of the id), without using a loop like:

```
List<String> valueList = new List<String>();
foreach (var resInList in reservationList) {
  valueList.Add(context.mtas.FirstOrDefault(id => id.mta_id == resInList.mta_id).mta_name);
}
```

I think this question already might be asked - but haven't found anything after searching for hours... thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you just want a LINQ join...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for join

```
var valueList = (from r in reservationList 
                 join m in context.mtas on r.mta_id equals m.mta_id
                 select r.mta_name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thx a lot (also to Jon Skeet) - that should do the job!